# Pattern for referencing array in JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

Consider a simple factory which self-updates -

```
function MyFactory(){

  var _data = []; // initial value

  function onLoad(response){

    // assign the incoming value to our '_data' variable
    _data = response;

  }

  // some sort of ajax to get the data
  function getData() {

     // ajax.fecth('/url', onLoad);

     // pseudo-ajax
     onLoad([4,5,6]);

  }

  // public methods / properties
  this.getData = getData;
  this.data = _data;

}
```

(Can you see the problem here? Worth taking a second.) I'll spell it out -

```
// create the object
var factory = new MyFactory();

// get the data
console.log(factory.data);  // [] ok

// get new data [1,2,3], and assign to the data property
factory.getData();

// what have we now got?
console.log(factory.data); // [] argh, expected [1,2,3]
```

This is not what we want at all. `this.data` should return the new array... but doesn't. It continues to reference the original array, even though we've internally updated our object.

There is a solution - instead of *replacing* the value of data, we can do this -

```
function onLoad(response){
    // take care to reuse the object
    _data.length = 0;
    Array.prototype.push.apply(_data, response);
}
```

... which is okay, but feels a bit of a hack.

My question is - what would be a better pattern of `MyFactory` which would ensure that we can update its `data` property so that it always returns the expected value.

Comment: `factory.data` is different from the variable `data` within the `myFactory` function. `factory.data` is `this.data` inside the `myFactory` function,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to MinusFour's answer, you have created a bit of confusion with *getData*. Usually, a getter gets a property of an object that is private. It's counterpart is setter that sets the value.

Your *getData* actually sets the "private" value (which is a closure), then you try to read it as a property. So if you just create a new getter and change *getData* to a setter, you're done:

```js
function MyFactory(){

  var _data = []; // initial value

  function onLoad(response){
    _data = response;
  }

  function getData() {
     onLoad([4,5,6]);
  }

  // setter to get data and set the value of _data
  this.setData = getData;

  // getter to return the value of _data
  this.getData = function() {
    return _data;
  };
}

// create the object
var factory = new MyFactory();

// get the data
document.write('data: ' + factory.getData());  // [] ok

// get new data [1,2,3], and assign to the data property
factory.setData();

// what have we now got?
document.write('<br>data: ' + factory.getData()); // expected [4,5,6]
```

You could overload the getter so that if you provide an argument, it sets the value immediately, or if no value is provided, do the AJAX thing.

Alternatively, you can define *data* as a getter:

```js
function MyFactory(){
  var _data = [];
  function onLoad(response){_data = response;}
  function getData() {onLoad([4,5,6]);}

  // public methods - setter and getter
  this.getData = getData;
  
  // Create a data property as a getter
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'data', {get: function() {return _data;}});
}


var factory = new MyFactory();
document.write('Data: ' + factory.data);  // [] ok
factory.getData();

// what have we now got?
document.write('<br>Data: ' + factory.data); // expected [4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably think that by doing:

```
this.data = _data;
```

You are actually linking both variables and whatever happens to `_data` will happen to `this.data`. This is not the case, it just end up copying the object reference. Which means that both variables are pointing to the same object reference (let's say the object is "A")

```
this.data === A
_data === A
```

What your `onLoad` method does is create a new object (lets call it "B") and assign it to `data`.

```
this.data === A
_data === B
```

`_data` is not part of the object unlike `this.data`, so it's not accessible from the object. This is why it doesn't work.

There's really no reason to work this way. You obviously want the `data` to be public, there's no reason to keep it in the constructor scope.

```
function MyFactory(){

  var that = this; // object reference which private methods can use

  function onLoad(response){

    // assign the incoming value to our '_data' variable
    that.data = response;

  }

  // some sort of ajax to get the data
  function getData() {

     // ajax.fecth('/url', onLoad);

     // pseudo-ajax
     onLoad([4,5,6]);

  }

  // public methods / properties
  this.getData = getData;
  this.data = [];

}
```

Comment: There is no need for *that*, the methods should always be called on their base object in this case.

Comment: @RobG, the problem is that `onLoad` is not part of the object. I assumed it's a private function hence why it's not attached. So you either save a reference to the object or use `call`, `apply` when invoking the private function.

Comment: Ah, you changed *data* to be public… I prefer to use an instance name, e.g. `var factory = this` rather than *that*, which has no semantic meaning.

Comment: I feel like it's a common practice though, either `that` or `self`. The important thing is to keep the object reference somewhere accessible to the private method. An arrow function might work better here I think, that way no binding need be done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider method *naming* conception. Create *public* **getter** method to access your *private* data on demand.

```
function MyFactory(){

  var _data = []; // initial value

  function onLoad(response){

    // assign the incoming value to our '_data' variable
    _data = response;

  }

  // some sort of ajax to get the data
  function loadData() {

     // ajax.fecth('/url', onLoad);

     // pseudo-ajax
     onLoad([4,5,6]);

  }

  // public methods / properties
  this.loadData = loadData;
  this.getData = function(){
      return _data;
  }

}
```